# How to Extract Roles from JWT Claims in ASP.NET Core When Roles are Stored as an Array?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, claimsprincipal

I'm working with JWT authentication in an ASP.NET Core application and encountering an issue when trying to extract role claims from the ClaimsPrincipal. My JWT payload has the roles stored as a JSON array under the claim type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role". Here's an example of the payload:

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "1",
  "email": "tunahan.ali.ozturk@outlook.com",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "Tunahan Ozturk",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": [
    "agents.admin",
    "users.admin"
  ],
  "nbf": 1708900840,
  "exp": 1708901440,
  "iss": "doing@doing.com",
  "aud": "doing@doing.com"
}
```

I'm attempting to retrieve the roles in my middleware using an extension method on ClaimsPrincipal, like so:

```
public static List<string>? ClaimRoles(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    const string RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
    return claimsPrincipal?.Claims(RoleClaimType);
}
```

However, this method isn't working, and I'm not sure why. The roles are not being extracted, and I end up receiving an error when the method is called. Here's how I'm using this method within my middleware:

```
public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    List<string>? roleClaims = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.ClaimRoles();

    if (roleClaims == null) throw new AuthorizationException("Claims not found.");

    bool isNotMatchedARoleClaimWithRequestRoles = roleClaims.FirstOrDefault(roleClaim => request.Roles.Any(role => role == roleClaim)).IsNullOrEmpty();

    if (isNotMatchedARoleClaimWithRequestRoles) throw new AuthorizationException("You are not authorized.");

    TResponse response = await next();

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the claims the roles are not in the same list by default.
[image]

So the extension method would be like

```
        public static List<string>? ClaimRoles(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            const string RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
            var roleClaims = claimsPrincipal?.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == RoleClaimType);
            return roleClaims.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I tried it, and it will be the same, I don't know why but It's working on Postman.

Comment: @moongazing That's strange. Is there any difference of all the claims in httpcontext compraring with using postman or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

Note:-(model.Token is deserialized token)

var jwt = handler.ReadJwtToken(model.Token);
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, jwt.Claims.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Type == "role").Value));
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
if (principal.IsInRole("Customer"))
{
                
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).